# How is defined the data type FXPT2DOT30 in the BMP file structure?

Tags: bmp

The type FXPT2DOT30 appears in defining the struct CIEXYZ for BMP files, 
according to the definition provided by Microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371828(v=vs.85).aspx

However, I cannot found the exact definition of FXPT2DOT30 anywhere.
Which is its precise definition? 
What kind of data is supposed to hold?

Comment: This question is answered [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=giW4IIY_eMoC&pg=PT1211&lpg=PT1211&dq=FXPT2DOT30+fixed+point&source=bl&ots=dY_4AhLwGa&sig=CYG_MxoqzYVPcsjPSMSOooeJP_A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DWzDUpnHJNSrhAefuIHACA&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=FXPT2DOT30%20fixed%20point&f=false)

Answer (score 8):

@RobinGreen provided a [link](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=giW4IIY_eMoC&pg=PT1211&lpg=PT1211&dq=FXPT2DOT30%20fixed%20point&source=bl&ots=dY_4AhLwGa&sig=CYG_MxoqzYVPcsjPSMSOooeJP_A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DWzDUpnHJNSrhAefuIHACA&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=FXPT2DOT30%20fixed%20point&f=false):

There it is the answer to my question:

> [...] FXPT2DOT30 [...] which means that they are interpreted as fixed-point values with a 2-bit integer part and a 30-bit fractional part.

Answer (score 2):

According to [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm) here is an unpacked version of the [`BITMAPV4HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183380(v=vs.85).aspx) structure.  The fields between `CSType` and `GammaRed` correspond to the `CIEXYZTRIPLE bV4Endpoints` in `BITMAPV4HEADER`.

```
typedef struct _Win4xBitmapHeader
{
    DWORD Size;            /* Size of this header in bytes */
    LONG  Width;           /* Image width in pixels */
    LONG  Height;          /* Image height in pixels */
    WORD  Planes;          /* Number of color planes */
    WORD  BitsPerPixel;    /* Number of bits per pixel */
    DWORD Compression;     /* Compression methods used */
    DWORD SizeOfBitmap;    /* Size of bitmap in bytes */
    LONG  HorzResolution;  /* Horizontal resolution in pixels per meter */
    LONG  VertResolution;  /* Vertical resolution in pixels per meter */
    DWORD ColorsUsed;      /* Number of colors in the image */
    DWORD ColorsImportant; /* Minimum number of important colors */
    /* Fields added for Windows 4.x follow this line */

    DWORD RedMask;       /* Mask identifying bits of red component */
    DWORD GreenMask;     /* Mask identifying bits of green component */
    DWORD BlueMask;      /* Mask identifying bits of blue component */
    DWORD AlphaMask;     /* Mask identifying bits of alpha component */
    DWORD CSType;        /* Color space type */
    LONG  RedX;          /* X coordinate of red endpoint */
    LONG  RedY;          /* Y coordinate of red endpoint */
    LONG  RedZ;          /* Z coordinate of red endpoint */
    LONG  GreenX;        /* X coordinate of green endpoint */
    LONG  GreenY;        /* Y coordinate of green endpoint */
    LONG  GreenZ;        /* Z coordinate of green endpoint */
    LONG  BlueX;         /* X coordinate of blue endpoint */
    LONG  BlueY;         /* Y coordinate of blue endpoint */
    LONG  BlueZ;         /* Z coordinate of blue endpoint */
    DWORD GammaRed;      /* Gamma red coordinate scale value */
    DWORD GammaGreen;    /* Gamma green coordinate scale value */
    DWORD GammaBlue;     /* Gamma blue coordinate scale value */
} WIN4XBITMAPHEADER;
```

Answer (score 0):

From `gdiplus.h`:

```
typedef long FXPT2DOT30, FAR *LPFXPT2DOT30;

typedef struct tagCIEXYZ
{
        FXPT2DOT30 ciexyzX;
        FXPT2DOT30 ciexyzY;
        FXPT2DOT30 ciexyzZ;
} CIEXYZ;
```